# Why private variable declared outside the class can be access Class on the same file?

Tags: ios, swift

While studying iOS stuffs, I encountered this `private var` declared outside the class on the same file that it can access the private var in any class. Private definition is any type that can be access only within the class itself, but not other class.

```
private let outside: String = "private-let?"

class LoginVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        print(outside)
    }
}
```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson "Or is it so that in this case the access control automatically falls back to file-private?" Yes, exactly. This is well documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`private` is intended for use inside a type declaration. Otherwise it has no meaning.  When `private` is used in a place where it has no meaning, it is reinterpreted as `fileprivate`. That is what happens here.  This code is in the same file so the `fileprivate` variable is visible.

Answer (score 2):

Declaring any variables outside scope of class or struct will make it a **Global Variable**.

```
private let outside: String = "private-let?"

class LoginVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        print(outside)
    }
}
```

So in your case even you create a private constant or variable globally it will be available inside all the class you defined in that file. So the access level will be considered to that file-level scope.

If you make it public it will be available in other file classes as well.

Read more about the variables [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html)

Read more about the [access control](http://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html)

Comment: thanks for reply, but it declared as a private, not fileprivate. As far as I know, when the variable declared as fileprivate, it can be access anywhere only on that file. On the other hand, that means that the private let outside variable becomes sort of fileprivate?

Comment: @IrisReyes When you declare the variable as global the access level private will be applicable as private for that file and that means it will be not accessible outside of file but accessible inside. fileprivate & private will have same behaviour when its global var or let.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html Read this completely to get the idea how if will infer the access levell.

Answer (score 1):

Let say we have a file `Helper.swift` and since our **private variable** is **outside the class** which makes it **Globally accessible**.

You will **not get any compile time error** while **accessing private member** because your **classes are in same file**. But if two classes were in different file then you would get compile time error.

```
//Since this private variable is outside the class So its Global and accessible to any class within file.
private var secretCode : String? = nil

class MyPrivateData {
 init() {
    secretCode = "First change"
  }
}

class MySecondClass {

    init() {
       secretCode = "Second change"
    }

}
```

Comment: This would work if it was fileprivate. You cannot access a private class member into other class.

Comment: Yeah right. But here in your case private variable isn't defined inside any class so it is accessible from any class in same file. Because it doesn't belongs to any class

Comment: Indeed. But in your example code it is defined inside a class so that will give you compile time error.

Comment: @ParthAdroja I missed it before. Then I corrected in comment. Thanks

Comment: @Kudos, but the definition of private from Swift docs is "Private access restricts the use of an entity to the enclosing declaration, and to extensions of that declaration that are in the same file". private let outside lies outside the class and didn't declared inside any enclosing block of class, struct, functions, etc. fileprivate might be reasonable here since its definition is accessible on the same file, but my question is why is it accessible even it didn't declared inside block of class, struct.

Comment: @IrisReyes PLease check here https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html  "Private access restricts the use of an entity to the enclosing declaration" Since here is not enclosing declaration so its accessible throughout the class. And u can say its working like FilePrivate.